# error in awk: "cannot open - too many open files"

Tags: unix, awk

I need to split a huge file (about 4 million lines) in subfiles based on a pattern.

I always use awk to do that and works perfectly in files until about a hundred thousand lines. Files bigger than that are returning the following error:

```
awk: cannot open "filename" for output (Too many open files)
```

Here the command line that I'm using:

```
awk '{OFS="\t"; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$12 > $10"_"$8.txt"}' mybigfile.txt
```

In `$10` there are about 4 or 5 thousand different patterns in which I need to split into.

How can I overcome this error? Where should I insert the `close` command?
(I'm using the awk in the Ubuntu distribution.)

Comment: Count the double quotes in your command and notice it's an odd number. Now think about what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy/paste exactly this command and it **will** work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {out=$10"_"$8".txt"; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$12 >> out; close(out)}' mybigfile.txt
```

You've been experiencing 2 problems:

1) You're using an awk that is not GNU awk and so doesn't close files for you when needed, and

2) You're re-typing the commands people are suggesting you use instead of copy-pasting them and messing up the quotes when you do so, just like in the script in your question.

If you can use gawk then it'd simply be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$12 > ($10"_"$8".txt")}' mybigfile.txt
```

Unlike with several other awks you don't technically **need** to parenthesize the expression on the right side of output redirection with gawk but it's a good habit to get into for portability and helps readability.

Comment: Ed, thank you very much for your instructions. I used the first command that you suggested and work perfectly (actually I'll check some files manually just to be sure, but I think it is perfect).
Thanks to everyone who took their time to help me with this, much thankful.
Just as curiosity: this run took more than 1 hour to complete...

Comment: You're welcome. FYI it wouldn't take anything like that long if your input was sorted appropriately but since you didn't provide any sample input/output all we could do was help you fix your script, not improve your approach.

Answer (score 1):

So whenever you are creating a new file by values of $10, $8 then it will write the lines into it but in backend since awk program is still running it will not close those files and which will cause the limit of open files by this awk program thus we have to close those files.

Kindly try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";} {if(prev){close(prev)};print $1,$2,$3,$4,$12 >> ($10"_"$8".txt");prev=$10"_"$8".txt"}' mybigfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Ravinder!
Unfortunately didn't work. First returned these errors:
awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
awk: line 1: runaway string constant "} ...

Then I took off the ".txt" extension and started to run, and returned just one file, literally named "$10$8" (weird).

Looks like that all the new splited files were put into the same $10$8 file, overwriting the entire previous data

Comment: not sure but it is working for me, which O.S are you using? If you are using on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk , or nawk.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu as a virtual machine... trying to solv this, I don't have too much experience in awk.. thank you anyway!!